# Displaying static text on a view that disappears after hitting 'Search'?

Tags: views, search

I have a view with a Search block exposed to users. What I would like to achieve is:

I would like to display a text in the View's body itself under the Search box. This text should disappear once a user enters a term and hit 'Search".

Is this doable? I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Let me just clarify on that. The requirement is that you want have blank page with an instruction to search on the view page to start of with and only display result when you apply the filter is this what you are trying to chive?

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. What I want to achieve is that: the page with the Views that has a search box will have some text below the search box that should disappear once you enter a word in the search box and hit 'Search'. So, the text will be visible on the landing page and should disappear once you hit search. Any idea?

Comment: are you on views 6 or 7?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7, yes.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 there is an option to do it.

There are two exposed forms. By default basic is selected. there is another option called "input required" You can select that instead of Basic. This will make the result displayed only after entering the data.

You can also input the text that should be displayed before the search is made.